# AWS Lambda to Aurora RDS data transfer costs and networking architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I noticed that we are racking up quite a bit of data transfer costs from RDS. I would like to understand what is causing it and if our networking architecture is flawed.

So here's the architecture:

1. Aurora cluster running on (Availability Zone) AZ-c , belonging to 3 public subnets (1 for each AZ)
2. Lambda in 3 private subnets (1 for each AZ)
3. Lambda is allowed to communicate with the RDS instance through a security group

I think the only reason why the RDS instance is in a public subnet is to avoid using a proxy to connect to it from the office (we have an SG allowing access from the lambda and our office IP).

Should I try running the lambda only from 1 subnet, that is in the same AZ as the RDS cluster?

Comment: Is the Lambda function configured to use the same VPC as the Aurora cluster, or is it configured for "VPC: None"? Could the charged traffic be related to the queries being made from the office (which incurs Data Transfer costs)? Are those queries retrieving large datasets, or just calculated results?

Comment: They are in the same VPC. Now that I think if of it we have another team scraping our databases, so I will ask how often they do that. It returns a mixture of both computed and also datasets, but the datasets are limited to a particular month and the whole databases with data for 2 years is under 6GB, so 1 month of data is not that much. Do you think that lambda running on a different AZ subnet shouldn't cost?

Comment: So everyday there's 40GB of data out of the RDS, but by my calculations only 8GB should be scraped by the other team. So that still leaves 32GB of unknown transfers. Is there a way to see a more fine grained metric on that? I can only see that it's RDS, but not which cluster

Comment: I guess it is possible that all the data is going to the office, but still want to know if it's possible that lambda consumes some of it?

Comment: The AWS Lambda function would not be consuming Data Transfer, aside from a possible 2c/GB charge between AZs. This could be avoided by connecting Lambda to a subnet in the same AZ as the RDS database. Your Data Transfer charges are more likely to be caused by data exiting AWS and going to the Internet (eg to your office).

Comment: Thanks. Office consumption aside it's good to know that a lambda running on multiple AZs could be costing data transfer.